# python requests form recaptcha

Tags: python, python-requests, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

i've been trying to do a requests form using python but i'm blocked b the recaptcha.

I need the g-recaptcha-response to fill the entire form but i have no idea of how to get it.

I've been trying things but I have no clue of what i'm doing. I don't know anything about captcha.

here is my code:

```
url = url_add_to_cart
c.get(url)
c.post(url, data=add_to_cart_FORM, headers={"Refered": link_article})
page = c.get(link_article)
if (page.status_code == requests.codes.ok):
    print ("ok")
else:
    print ("not ok")

url1 = "https://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout.json"
c.get(url)

t = requests.get('http://ip.42.pl/raw')
tt = BeautifulSoup(t.text, 'html.parser')
ip = tt.text
print (ip)

page = c.get(link_checkout)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
find_class = soup.find(class_='g-recaptcha')
get_captcha_token = find_class.get('data-sitekey')
try:
    content = requests.post(
        'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
        data={
            'secret': RECAPTCHA_SECRET,
            'response': get_captcha_token,
            'remoteip': ip
        }
    ).content
except:
    print ("fail")
print (get_captcha_token)

c.post(url, data=payload_FORM, headers={"Refered": link_checkout})
page = c.get(link_checkout)
# page_to_print_for_test = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
# print (page_to_print_for_test.prettify())
if (page.status_code == requests.codes.ok):
    print ("ok")
else:
    print ("not ok")
```

here is the source code of captcha:

[image of the HTML code related to the captcha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWrTU.png)

If you need more infos, I will add everything!
thank you very much.

it is one of the last thing to do to finish my code. (I need to code it properly ^^)

Comment: you ever figure this out? I'm stuck on the same part for preme. A requests based bot would  likely be ineffective due to tohru js and pooky on preme's site so selenium is a better alternative but I'm still curious how to do this via requests.

Comment: nop never... you can DM me on twitter if needed @lucky_simFR

Comment: Will do. Check out https://github.com/dzt/captcha-harvester and https://github.com/ryan9918/captcha-harvester . Unfortunately, I believe this is what needs to be done. I plan on getting starting with learning flask and more so following Ryan's today. Luckily, flask is supposedly really easy to learn